# How do I select rows from table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm making an app where MainActivity has a RecyclerView that contains the user's lists e.g. grocery list, weekly list, etc.

When the user clicks on an item, it'll navigate to products activity also has a RecyclerView. I have 2 different SQLite databases 1:lists 2:products.

The logic I used is when a user adds a list, the lists database will record list name and id, also adds list name in products database, and when user add product, I used `update()` instead of `insert()` in `SQLite` because the column already exists, so product name and id will be updated in the product database.

This is the structure of the list and product table:

```
LISTS

  ID      LIST_NAME

1  1       list 1
2  2       list 2

PRODUCTS

  ID      LIST_NAME    PRODUCT_NAME

1  1       list 1     product1 in list1
2  2       list 1     product2 in list1
```

the problem is when I add a list then navigate to products I see this error :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: list (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM prducts WHERE LIST_NAME = list, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
```

this is the method inside `SQLiteOpenHelper` and the error shows in this line: `cursor = db.rawQuery(productsQuery, null);`

```
public Cursor getAllProducts(String list_name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (db != null)
        {
            String productsQuery = " SELECT * FROM " +DB_TABLE+ " WHERE "+LIST_NAME_COLUMN+ " = "+list_name;
            cursor = db.rawQuery(productsQuery, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

in product activity i used `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();` to pass the list name from list activity. and in list activity i used `intent.putExtra("list_name", list_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the value of the string `list_name` uquoted in the sql statement, so it is considered as a column name.
Use a `?` placeholder in your query and pass `list_name` as the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
String productsQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " + LIST_NAME_COLUMN + " = ?";
cursor = db.rawQuery(productsQuery, new String[] {list_name});
```

This way you don't need to worry about quoting the parameters that you pass to the query.

Comment: thank you for your answer @forpas the error is gone but the items in `ProductsActivity` are not showing although it's in the database! unless the query is like this: `"SELECT * FROM"+DB_TABLE ` but it shows the entire table

Comment: @FathiOmer This is a different requirement. Post a new question with the code that populates the recyclerview to clarify.

Comment: my bad there was a conflict between `update()` and `insert()` in sqlite. thank you @forpas